# Why don't these two R lines produce the same output?

Tags: r, stringr

I recently started fooling around with `R`, and for the life of me can't figure out why these two pieces of code don't produce the same output:

```
 data.short[which(str_detect(data.short$name, "Miss")),]
 data.short[which(grep("Miss", data.short$name) > 1),]
```

From the definitions of the two functions `str_detect` and `grep` I understand, these two lines are essentially the same; filter out only the entries which contain "Miss" in their names.

The first code does exactly that. The second code, however, fails to do anything. Could someone please explain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, these two codes are not doing the same thing.

tl;dr

These two lines of code are similar

```
data.short[which(str_detect(data.short$name, "Miss")),]

data.short[grep("Miss", data.short$name),]
```

---

In case, if you are interested knowing **why**

Let's take a reproducible example,

```
x <- c("one", "onetwo", "two", "threeone", "three")
```

Let's get the indices of the elements which has "one" in it

- `str_detect`

`str_detect` returns `TRUE`/`FALSE` values, so if we want indices we wrap `which` around it

```
library(stringr)
which(str_detect(x, "one"))
#[1] 1 2 4
```

This is correct as vector elements at position 1, 2 and 4 have "one" in it.

Now, let's move to `grep`

```
grep("one", x)
#[1] 1 2 4
```

This already gives the expected output which you want.

However, when you are doing

```
grep("one", x) > 1
```

you are basically doing

```
c(1, 2, 4) > 1
```

which gives

```
[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

as 2 and 4 are greater than 1.

and now you wrap `which` over it which gives you indices of `TRUE` values which is 2 and 3 in this case

```
which(grep("one", x) > 1)
#[1] 2 3
```

Answer (score 3):

```
# for str_detect
library(stringr) 
# some mock-up data to use
data.short <- data.frame(name = c(rep("Mister", 3), rep("Miss", 3)))
```

Firstly,

```
data.short[which(str_detect(data.short$name, "Miss")),]
```

returns (as expected):

```
[1] Miss Miss Miss
Levels: Miss Mister
```

Secondly,

```
data.short[which(grep("Miss", data.short$name) > 1),]
```

returns:

```
[1] Mister Mister Mister
Levels: Miss Mister
```

This is because the following returns

```
grep("Miss", data.short$name)
[1] 4 5 6
```

and if you subject that to a "which is larger than 1", you get:

```
which(grep("Miss", data.short$name) > 1)
[1] 1 2 3
```

finally yielding elements with index 1,2,3 (result of the last call) and not elements with index 4,5,6 which you probably intended:

```
data.short[which(grep("Miss", data.short$name) > 1),]
[1] Mister Mister Mister
Levels: Miss Mister
```

As a side note: `grep` has an argument `value`you can set to return the index or the value of the index:

```
> grep("Miss", data.short$name)
[1] 4 5 6
> grep("Miss", data.short$name, value = TRUE)
[1] "Miss" "Miss" "Miss"
```

### EDIT

Decomposing what happens with `str_detect`:

`str_detects` returns TRUE for those entries where the pattern is in the string

```
str_detect(data.short$name, "Miss")
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

`which` returns the index

```
which(str_detect(data.short$name, "Miss"))
[1] 4 5 6
```

and this in turn, used as an index, returns what you expect

```
data.short[which(str_detect(data.short$name, "Miss")),]
[1] Miss Miss Miss
Levels: Miss Mister
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I see. So explain something to me. How exactly does 'data.short[which(str_detect(data.short$name, "Miss")),]' operate? As I understand, it basically operates as a for loop, passing through every observation in the table, passing the [name] column of that entry into the str_detect function, and returning it only if that returns true. Is that not a correct execution model?

Comment: @Gummybears, I will add some lines to my answer

Comment: Ahh... now it makes sense. As a follow-up question; suppose I only want to access specific row entries. data.short[(1,3,5),] doesn't seem to work, although data.short[(1:3),] works perfectly.

Comment: @Gummybears `1:3` returns a numeric vector, identical to `c(1,2,3)`. If you would use `c(1,3,5)` your subsetting would work again.